# How do I remove the file extension from a list of files in an NSArray in iOS 5

Tags: ios

Working in iOS 5 I have read a list of file names from my documents directory the array is called "file list". I am trying to get a list of file names without extensions. Only the last name in my list has the extension removed. Any ideas?

```
- (IBAction)getFile:(id)sender
{  
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory =[paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *fileList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
    NSString *names = [[[fileList valueForKey:@"description"]componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"]stringByDeletingPathExtension];

    NSLog(@"File Name Is \n%@",names);    
    showFile.text = names; 
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)getFile:(id)sender
{  
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory =[paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *fileList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
    NSString *names = nil;
    for (NSString *name in fileList){
        if (!names) names = [[name lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
        else names = [names stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@",[[name lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension]];
    }
    NSLog(@"File Name Is \n%@",names
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using the description of the array to get the full array contents, and then you are removing the file extension for the whole thing rather than from each individual file. Try removing the filename extensions first:

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[fileList count]];
[fileList enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [newArray addObject:[obj stringByDeletingPathExtension]];
}];
NSString *names = [newArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
showFile.text = names;
```

The `enumerateObjectsUsingBock` method goes through each item in the array. In the code block you take that object, delete the path extension, and add it to a new array. After the full array has been processed, you can them use `componentsJoinedByString` to add the newline between each filename.